# Why are files copied over usb to be 0 bytes?

Tags: ubuntu, zfs, nvme, exfat

This is a recurrent topic and I have read some answers on serverfault amongst them:

[Folder sizes differ within two copied NTFS file trees (using ntfs-3g)](https://serverfault.com/questions/538952/folder-sizes-differ-within-two-copied-ntfs-file-trees-using-ntfs-3g)

We have a ubuntu client from which researchers can export to their usb drive or dongle DICOM files that they have scanned with MRI. Typically, it consists of hundreds of files with size from 100kB to a couple of MB in 10 folders. So an exam that is copied can be 3 GB in total.
In order to avoid having people plugin in their drive with potential viruses in the windows driven MRI scanner, I've programmed a transfer of the images to a ubuntu 22.04 client where people can download their data. Now some of them get 0 byte files. Here are my thoughts:

1. I first thought it was because of the format they use on their drives which is often exfat and have recommended ntfs. I have so far no report of 0 byte on ntfs.
2. When the error happens, the copying process is extremely fast.
3. I have also recommended using rsync (actually grsync) in order to get a checksum on the target. Some of them, not all of the users, apparently still get the 0 byte files although the system says the copying was done successfully. On the ubuntu client, there are no 0 byte files. But then when they read data on their mac or windows computer, the size of some of the files is 0.

With the same drives they never got the error on the windows driven MRI computer. What can be the issue? The source files are good.

My setup:
Ubuntu 22.04
Nvme drive 2TB × 2 in zfs mirror
Hdd long term storage 20TB x 2 zfs mirror (data is transferred from nvme to there after 24h)

Is the problem zfs, nvme driver or bad partitions on the exfat dongles?

Thanks

Comment: My first thought would be that people don't unmount the drive before removing it.

Comment: Thank you Gerald! I will make some tests. But now that you mention this I noticed yesterday that when pushing the unmount "arrow"-like button in nautilus, a pop-up window came up and last for ever making it impossible to know if the drive was still mounted or not. This would lead me to another question: why does this not happen in Windows?

Comment: Windows handles USB drives differently. It detects the type of drive and mounts most modern drives without writing cache, so an unmount is not necessary. Linux always uses a write cache by default.

Comment: Thanks again. Then is it ok to push on the unmount button even if it hangs or should I wait 5 minutes before pushing? (I can't ask them to write unmount in terminal).

Comment: It doesn't matter when you start the unmount process, it will only end when all data is written on the disk. How long this takes depends on the amount of data and the write speed of the drive.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gerald! I'll give new instructions taking into account your recommendations. I'll get back on the thread after a test period to give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gerald, you were totally right!
I made some tests and could reproduce the 0 byte error by just plugging out the usb flash drive when rsync or nautilus copying were said to be done. Once I red the files on Windows, some of the files had 0 byte in size.
Then I did the same test but this time I properly unmounted the drive. The files had time to be sync:ed and were correct once read in Windows.
The sync can take some time so if many large files are involved one should read on the top of the screen: "device should not be unplugged" after pushing the unmount button in nautilus. Wait until you can read: "Device can be removed".

Comment: Use `rsync … ; sync` and it'll wait until the data has been flushed to the USB device

Comment: It should be possible to modify udev rules to disable the write cache for attached USB devices. This will make the copy process appear slower, but it will show a more realistic process for the user and should reduce error potential.